# Android open file from my application into suitable application installed error

Tags: java, android, filechooser

I have the following code to launch application chooser to open any type of file, but when ever I try to open the file I get the message file cannot be opened.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(path));

if(type.contains("image")) {
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path),type);
}else if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")){
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path),"text/plain");
}else{
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path),type);
}                       

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
Intent intentOpen = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");

try {
  activity.startActivity(intentOpen);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {                  
}
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`.

Comment: What is the value of `path`? What is the value of `type`?

Comment: type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"  and path="/storage/emulated/0/Download/ws.docx" the path i get from root=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i had to add file:// at the start of the path to open the file.

```
path="file://"+Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOA‌​DS).getPath()+"/"+myFileName;
```